# Renaming multiple files by removing a single number (1 & 2) in each file

Tags: bash, rename, perl

I have approx 200 files named in the format:

```
paired_dat_11_R1.fq
paired_dat_12_R2.fq 
paired_dat_121_R1.fq
paired_dat_122_R2.fq
paired_dat_851_R1.fq
paired_dat_852_R2.fq
```

I just would like to rename the `2` to `1`, while leaving the `R1` and `R2` values intact:

```
paired_dat_11_R1.fq 
paired_dat_11_R2.fq 
paired_dat_121_R1.fq
paired_dat_121_R2.fq
paired_dat_851_R1.fq
paired_dat_851_R2.fq
```

Comment: Yes, the perl rename command. Even the default file manager could do that.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Change all `12` to `11`? Change `2` to `1`? Change `2` to its previous number? [Edit] your question and be more specific. Also add a few more items to your example input and output formats so we can understand better.

Comment: Yes, I want to change `2` to `1` so the ID number is the same while leaving the `R1` and `R2` alone since those correspond to forward and reverse ends of the genome.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `mmv` (install it with `sudo apt install mmv`) as follows:

```
mmv -n 'paired_dat_*2_R2*' 'paired_dat_#1\1_R2#2'
```

`-n` is used so that you can preview the changes without applying them to your files. If you are satisfied with the output, run the command without `-n`.

**How this works**

`mmv` comprises of a filename matching part (`'paired_dat_*2_R2*'` here) and a replacement part (`'paired_dat_#1\1_R2#2'` here).

In the first part we use wildcards to match parts of the filename which allows for using these matches to rename the files.

In the above command the `*` wildcard is used, which means "match any character". The first `*` matches the characters between `paired_dat_` and `2_R2`, while the second `*` matches the characters from `2_R2` to the end of the filename.

Each match can be then used in the replacement part using `#` followed by ascending numbers that correspond to the match. So `#1` corresponds to the match of the first `*` and `#2` to the second match of `*`. Since the first `*` matches up to `2` without including it, using `#1` in the replacement part essentially removes it. We then add `1_R2` (`1` should be escaped, thus we use `\1`) and then we add the rest of the filename as `#2`.

You can find more details by running in a terminal [`man mmv`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/mmv.1.html).

---

There is also a GUI option using Nautilus, which is similar to what [Artur Meinild](https://askubuntu.com/users/1066942/artur-meinild) suggests in [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1426908/618353):

- Open Nautilus.
- Navigate to the directory with your files.
- Select your files.
- <kbd>right-click</kbd> and select *Rename* or press <kbd>F2</kbd>.
- In the window that pops up select *Find and replace text*.
- In the *Existing Text* field enter: `2_R2`
- In the *Replace With* field enter: `1_R2`
- Click <kbd>Replace</kbd> and your files will be renamed!

[image: nautilus renaming]

As always, test this first on a copied portion of the files to make sure that it works as intended.

Answer (score 2):

Install the [Perl `rename` command](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man1/prename.1p.html), if it's not already present (it wasn't on my system by default):

```
sudo apt install rename
```

Run this command to do the change you describe:

```
rename 's/2_R2/1_R2/' paired_dat*.fq
```

The syntax is equivalent to that of the [`sed` command](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/sed.1posix.html).

Also see [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1136/batch-renaming-files) on Unix & Linux.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying using rename but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Krusader](https://krusader.org/)'s MultiRename. It takes `????` for single characters and like in the above answer you can see the results before applying them. It is essentially just a GUI for `krename`.

Comment: It would be nice if you could [edit] your answer and be a bit more detailed about how Krusader could be used for the particular OP's case. Thanks!

Comment: yes it would be nice, and time consuming. I accept the downvote though. http://multicommander.com/docs/MultiRename